# Validate app CFBundleVersion bundle invalid

Tags: xcode

Sorry my english is not vers good.

I cannot validare archive, old version is 1.4.7(4) , New version bundle is 2.50,  I dont understand the problem,  2.50 > 1.4.7

Je n’arrive pas à valider une nouvelle archive avec xcode, il indique que le numéro de lanouvelle version doit être supérieur à l'ancienne,  ce qui semble le cas.

An idea ?

Tanks